# Convert string to datetime format ex 2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, datetime

I have a string which I believe is in ISO8601 format, example `2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z`. How can I convert this string to the type `datetime` so I can save it?

I think rails requires you to also save the timezone when saving a datetime.

I have tried using Date.parse(2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'date'

# If you want the date & time
DateTime.parse('2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z')

# If you only care about the date
Date.parse('2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z')
```

Testing under 2.1.1p76

```
~|⇒ ruby -v      
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
~|⇒ irb    
2.1.1 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > dt = DateTime.parse('2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z')
 => #<DateTime: 2010-02-11T14:54:27+00:00 ((2455239j,53667s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.1.1 :003 > puts dt.to_s
2010-02-11T14:54:27+00:00
```

Comment: Those examples work for me. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @user3646037, I updated to show my output on 2.1.1p76. Perhaps another gem is conflicting with the DateTime parsing.  What other gems do you have installed?

Comment: Hold on isn't the datetime format supposed to be like 2014-07-17 21:47:03.987404

Comment: `2010-02-11T14:54:27.000Z` is valid.  It's 2:54:27.000 PM UTC

Comment: Sorry I had an unrelated error in my code. You are right, there is no need to convert this string you can just assign it as type datetime.